# Error dismounting pcie device windows - The current configuration does not allow for OS control of the PCI Express bus

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, passthrough

I have all of the virtualization options I know of in my bios enabled. I'm able to do VFIO in linux to a windows guest, but I'd like to do windows with passthrough to a linux guest using hyper-v. I get the following error attempting to dismount the device:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Dismount-VMHostAssignableDevice -force -LocationPath "PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1B04)#PCI(0000)"
Dismount-VMHostAssignableDevice : The operation failed.
The current configuration does not allow for OS control of the PCI Express bus. Please check your BIOS or UEFI
settings.
At line:1 char:1
+ Dismount-VMHostAssignableDevice -force -LocationPath "PCIROOT(0)#PCI( ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Dismount-VMHostAssignableDevice], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.DismountVMHostAssignableDevice
```

Board info:

```
Manufacturer           Product                        Version
ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.  ROG MAXIMUS X HERO (WI-FI AC)  Rev 1.xx
```

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out:
In your bios set the following to enabled:
Advanced\ Platform Misc Configuration\ PCI Express Native Power Management

I also set its child that appeared to enabled, although I'm not sure of the ramifications other then it fixed my issue.